# jQuery $.ajax does not work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I wrote a code using jQuery plugin fullcalendar, and everything worked just fine, until I send an $.ajax request in the eventClick.

I tried to alert something in the eventClick and it worked, but the ajax request just doesn't work.
js code:

```
            !function($)
        {

            $(document).ready(function() {

                $("#eventDialog").dialog({
                    autoOpen : false,
                    modal : true
                });

                var date = new Date();
                var d = date.getDay();
                var m = date.getMonth();
                var y = date.getFullYear();

                $("#calendar").fullCalendar({

                    theme : true,

                    header : {
                        left : 'next,prev today',
                        center : 'title',
                        right : 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                    },

                    editable : false,

                    events : [
                        <?php
                            while ($event = mysql_fetch_array($selectevents))
                            {
                                $startd = explode(".", $event['start']);
                                $endd = explode(".", $event['end']);

                                $starth = explode(":", $event['starth']);
                                $endh = explode(":", $event['endh']);
                        ?>
                        {

                            id : <?php echo $event['id']; ?>,
                            title : '<?php echo stripslashes($event['title']); ?>',
                            <?php
                                if ($event['allday'] == 1)
                                {
                            ?>
                            start : new Date(<?php echo $startd[2]; ?>,<?php echo $startd[1]-1; ?>,<?php echo $startd[0]; ?>),
                            end : new Date(<?php echo $endd[2]; ?>,<?php echo $endd[1]-1; ?>,<?php echo $endd[0]; ?>)
                            <?php
                                }
                                else
                                {
                            ?>
                            start : new Date(<?php echo $startd[2]; ?>,<?php echo $startd[1]-1; ?>,<?php echo $startd[0]; ?>,<?php echo $starth[0]; ?>,<?php echo $starth[1]; ?>),
                            end : new Date(<?php echo $endd[2]; ?>,<?php echo $endd[1]-1; ?>,<?php echo $endd[0]; ?>,<?php echo $endh[0]; ?>,<?php echo $endh[1]; ?>),
                            allDay : false
                            <?php
                                }
                            ?>
                        }
                        <?php
                                $evNum--;
                                if ($evNum > 0)
                                    echo ",";
                            }
                        ?>
                    ],

                    eventClick : function(event) {

                        var eid = event.id;

                        $.ajax({
                            type : "GET",
                            url : "getEvent.php",
                            data : "id=" + eid,
                            succuss : function(msg) {

                                var title = $("event title", msg).text();
                                var description = $("event description", msg).text();
                                var start = $("event start", msg).text();
                                var end = $("event end", msg).text();
                                var starth = $("event starth", msg).text();
                                var endh = $("event endh", msg).text();

                                $("#eventDialog").attr("title", title);
                                $("#eventDialog #edDescription").html(title);

                                eventDialog.dialog("open");

                            }
                        });

                    }

                });

            });

        }(jQuery);
```

getEvent.php

```
    $id = htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']));

$selectevent = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `calendar` WHERE `id`='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
$event = mysql_fetch_array($selectevent);

header("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>';

echo "<event>";
echo "<id>".$event['id']."</id>";
echo "<title>".stripslashes($event['title'])."</title>";
echo "<description>".$event['description']."</description>";
echo "<start>".$event['start']."</start>";
echo "<end>".$event['end']."</end>";
echo "<starth>".$event['starth']."</starth>";
echo "<endh>".$event['endh']."</endh>";
echo "</event>";
```

Can anybody point out the problem?

Thank's!

Comment: Have you place PHP code in the javascript? PHP is a server side language and javascript is a client side.

Comment: Define "doesn't work." When you debug into it, where does it deviate from the expected execution path? Is the request being sent to the server? Is it receiving a response from the server? "Doesn't work" could mean anything.

Comment: @David Laberge: he is having the server side write the javascript BEFORE it gets sent to the client and executed. so yes this will work.. although, its not the greatest practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

succuss??, i guess is this your problem , it should be "success"

Comment: Ok, It's a line I deleted earlier by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Change `succuss` to  `success` in your code it must be a typo.

Since `jQuery` `$.ajax` did not find the `success` handler in its settings it didn't do anything.

Comment: OK, it's a line I deleted earlier. needed to change to $("#eventDialog").dialog("open");

Comment: Can you make sure the call is being made?